# How to get books of searched category in Google Books API?

Tags: google-books-api

I am using [Google Books API](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using) in my Angular project. I have list of different static categories of the Books. On click of particular category, I want to get books of the searched category from Google Books API. There is no API available in Google Books for this. Suggest me if there is any!

Right now i am using Google Books Search API for this purpose, but the search  result is not the same as it should be for category search. Suggest me alternate ways if any!

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `subject` keyword in your query to return results of that category.

Example:

`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=subject:fiction`

Comment: Thanks @Saurabh Thorat , i will definitely try this!

Comment: This is also not working properly! Not giving exact output.